# How to create a line chart based on triplets with the same z and different x and y

Tags: google-sheets, charts, pivot-table, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have this type of data:

```
+---+---+---+
| x | y | z |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | A |
+---+---+---+
| 2 | 3 | A |
+---+---+---+
| 4 | 4 | A |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 5 | B |
+---+---+---+
| 2 | 7 | B |
+---+---+---+
| 4 | 9 | B |
+---+---+---+
```

And I was trying to create a chart with two lines, one for A and one for B that have x as x-axis and y as y-axis.

I've been trying for a while fiddling with the chart editor but I can't seem to come up with something close.

Is there any way to create a lines chart based on that data, or I have to convert the data in a different format in order to draw the lines?

Comment: any pic of how should it look like?

Comment: on the legend you have A B, and two lines, one that passes through (1,2)(2,3)(4,4) and the other that passes through (1,5)(2,7)(4,9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if this is what you want:

[image: 0]

then formula is:

```
=QUERY(A2:C, "select B,sum(C) where A is not null group by B pivot A")
```

[image]